# How to start MongoDB as a service on OSX?

Tags: macos, mongodb

I am new to Mac OSX.
I use it to develop, can anybody tell me how to start MongoDB as a service on OSX?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Its generally good post educate to prove you've done something, or at least show what effort you've put or you'll get "google it" responses from senior guys.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my bash profile to start and stop at will (I have installed mongodb via homebrew).

```
alias mongo_start="launchctl load /usr/local/opt/mongodb/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist"
alias mongo_stop="launchctl unload /usr/local/opt/mongodb/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist"
```